# HTML5 progress element and MVVM

Tags: html, mvvm, angularjs, kendo-ui, progress-bar

I am using the KendoUI framework, but I suspect this will also happen in Angular, Backbone, etc.

I have an HTML5  element where I want both the value and the max driven by the VM.

I have tried this on a couple browsers, and it seems that attribute values for MAX and VALUE are fetched at INIT (HTML Layout), but are not later updated. Is this something that can be driven dynamically? My fallback will have to be JQuery.

```
<div class="Part">
    <progress id="ProgressBar"
        data-bind="attr: { max: TotalSize, value: TileCount }"></progress>100%
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, following seems to be working as expected (tested in Chrome+FF):

```
<progress value="{{ TileCount }}" max="{{ TotalSize }}"></progress>
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a KendoUI MVVM issue. Thanks.